# Como criar um número aleatório de 5 dígitos iniciando do 1?

Tags: java

Tenho que criar uma conta bancária com alguns requisitos, no meio deles preciso ter um número contante de 5 dígitos iniciados do 00001.

Porém ao colocar "00001" na hora de exibir só exibe o 2, 3 em diante. minha solução foi usar o número 10000. Porém queria saber como fazer de acordo com o enunciado.

```
public abstract class Account implements IBaseRate {

    String name;
    String sSN;
    double balence;
    String accountNumber;
    double rate;
    static int index = 00001;

...

private String setAccountNumber() {

    String lastSSN = sSN.substring(sSN.length()-2, sSN.length());
    int uniqueID = index++;
    int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random()*Math.pow(10, 3));

    return lastSSN + uniqueID + randomNumber;
}
}
```

Comment: 00001 é um número de **um dígito** formatado com zeros à esquerda.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema aí é que é preciso formatar o número da conta com zeros à esquerda para preencher a quantidade de casas que descreve.

Uma das formas de se fazer isto é usando o método [**`String.format`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), desta forma

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num = 1;
        String strNum = String.format("%05d", num);            
        System.out.println(strNum); // Saída: 00001
    }
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso276275)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado! Deu certo =D